# Arduino DUE + CMake with rosserial_arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

What is the board name I should use for BOARD?
The following does not work.

```
generate_arduino_firmware(due_project
  SRCS due_project.cpp ${ROS_LIB_DIR}/time.cpp
  BOARD due
  PORT /dev/ttyACM0
)
```

I have installed DUE related stuff in IDE by Tools -> Boards Manager. I just want the arduino things to be built using catkin just like other packages. Also, I noticed that /home/peshala/arduino-1.6.5-r5/hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt does not contain an entry for "due".

Thank you.

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225519/arduino-due-+-cmake-with-rosserial_arduino/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-02-01**:
The due is not an avr processor, it will be under sam.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2016-02-01**:
@tonybaltovski ok I understand. So, what modifications should I make to compile and upload to DUE as in [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello i work for me with arduino1.6.8
i change in ros_lib the file ArduinoHardware.h
#if defined(USBCON) and !(defined(USE_USBCON))
/* Leonardo support */
iostream = &Serial1;

to

#if defined(USBCON) and !(defined(USE_USBCON))
/* Leonardo support */
iostream = &Serial;

---

Originally posted by [laazizi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26883/laazizi/) with karma: 16 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0